# Installed on whole hard drive of UEFI enabled PC. Now can't boot

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, asus

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on an Asus PC (specs below) direct from a live USB, over the existing Windows install with a custom partition scheme and now the hard drive is no longer recognised.

On booting I'm told to activate CSM, which I completed through the BIOS. Now each time the machine tries to boot and then takes me straight to the BIOS.

Have I bricked this new machine? Is it possible to alter the BIOS settings to allow the machine to boot into Ubuntu?

```
OVERVIEW
Type    Desktop
Operating system    Windows 10 (64-bit)
SPECIFICATION
Processor   - Intel® Core™ i3-4170
- Dual-core
- 3.7 GHz
- 3 MB
Memory (RAM)    8 GB
Graphics card   NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 (1 GB)
Storage 2 TB HDD, 7200 rpm
Motherboard Intel® H81
```

Answer (score 0):

At BIOS setting(press F2 after powered your machine), set booting from UEFI, instead of Legacy

Comment: unfortunately those options are mutually exclusive. where I set legacy vs UEFI can only be selected if CSM is disabled, taking me back to where I was...

Answer (score 0):

Is is very unlikely that your machine is bricked from simply installing Ubuntu on your hard drive.

Yes it is possible to alter your bios settings to try to boot into your (if correctly installed) Ubuntu instance. As linerd said, try changing the Booting option to UEFI or both instead of Legacy.

Also, more details would be appreciated, sometimes the computer will boot on the hard drive and an error message like "No operating was found", don't you have any of that?